Receive MultiValueMap multipart/form-data with RestTemplate
I have problem with this case, hope somebody will help me.
So I have mocked get server:
@GetMapping(value = "/getMsgFileExt",
            produces = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<MultiValueMap<String, Object>> getMsgFileExt() throws IOException {
    MultiValueMap<String, Object> formData = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
    Path path = Paths.get("C:\\Users\\User\\IdeaProjects\\ccgw_sources\\TKmock\\src\\main\\resources\\test.txt.zip.total.zip");
    formData.add("xml", respDataMsgInfo);
    formData.add("zip", Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(Files.readAllBytes(path)));
        return new ResponseEntity<>(formData, HttpStatus.OK);
}

And Receiver on client side :
String uri = String.format("%s/getMsgFileExt", customsUrl);

UriComponents builder = UriComponentsBuilder.fromHttpUrl(uri)
  .queryParam("id", id)
  .build();

 ResponseEntity<MultiValueMap<String, Object>> response = customsCardRestTemplate.exchange(builder.toUriString(), HttpMethod.GET,
                                                                                                  null,
                                                                                                  new ParameterizedTypeReference<>() {});
MultiValueMap<String, Object> map = response.getBody();

But i got this exception :
Could not extract response: no suitable HttpMessageConverter found for response type [org.springframework.util.MultiValueMap<java.lang.String, java.lang.Object>] and content type [multipart/form-data]

I already read this topic RestTemplate & multipart/form-data response, but I am sure that spring boot has another solution.
Or Maybe we have another way to send/receive multipart with xml and zip?
